Error cargar eventos calendario Google mediante API
Estoy desarrollando una conexion de mi aplicacion web con la API de Google relacionada al calendario permitiendo al usuario ver los eventos de su calendario de Google.
Mi código te permite iniciar sesión desde la barra de navegación y redirigir a la página del calendario, pero tengo un error al renderizar/cargar los eventos, estos errores aparecen en la consola pero muestra el calendario vacío:

[GSI_LOGGER]: Failed to open popup window on url:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?gsiwebsdk=3&client_id=1073983126772-tqah7gc4gosatejv44ohjlmjltf612hk.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttps%2Fdev.documanager.es%3Fid%3Dauth197029&prompt=consent&login_hint=user%40example.com&response_type=token&include_granted_scopes=true&enable_granular_consent=true.
Maybe blocked by the browser?
ai @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:170
h @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:170
bi @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:171
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:171
d @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:130
b @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:126
calendarGoogle:944 Error fetching events: {result: {…}, body: '{\n
"error": {\n "errors": [\n {\n "domain": "gl… ],\n "code": 404,\n
"message": "Not Found"\n }\n}\n', headers: {…}, status: 404,
statusText: null}

si le doy al boton personalizado de refrescar que llama a la funcion loadCalendarEvents() entonces si se cargan los eventos
este es mi codigo:
calendarGoogle.php Aqui esta el calendario
<script>
    const HomeUrl = '<?php echo site_url('home'); ?>';

    let calendar;
    let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton logout',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            events: async function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                try {
                    const response = await gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                        'calendarId': 'primary',
                        'timeMin': fetchInfo.startStr,
                        'timeMax': fetchInfo.endStr,
                        'showDeleted': false,
                        'singleEvents': true,
                        'maxResults': 100,
                        'orderBy': 'startTime'
                    });
                    const events = response.result.items.map(event => {
                        return {
                            title: event.summary,
                            start: event.start.dateTime || event.start.date,
                            end: event.end.dateTime || event.end.date
                        };
                    });
                    successCallback(events);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error fetching events:', error);
                    failureCallback(error);
                }
            },
            customButtons: {
                myCustomButton: {
                    text: 'Refrescar',
                    click: function() {
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Actualizando calendario...',
                            allowOutsideClick: false,
                            didOpen: () => {
                                Swal.showLoading();
                                loadCalendarEvents();
                            },
                        });
                    },
                },
                logout: {
                    text: 'Cerrar Sesión',
                    click: function() {
                        cierre();
                    }
                }
            },
            buttonText: {
                today: 'Hoy',
                month: 'Mes',
                week: 'Semana',
                day: 'Día',
                list: 'Lista'
            },
            locale: 'es',
            firstDay: 1,
            dayMaxEvents: true,
            eventClick: function(info) {
                const event = info.event;
                const title = event.title;
                const start = event.start;
                const end = event.end;
                const allDay = event.allDay;
                const description = event.extendedProps.description || '--';
                const alert = event.extendedProps.alert || '';
                const task = event.extendedProps.task || '';

                let startFormatted, endFormatted;

                if (allDay) {
                    startFormatted = moment(start).format('Do MMM, YYYY');
                    endFormatted = end ? moment(end).format('Do MMM, YYYY') : 'Sin fecha de fin';
                } else {
                    startFormatted = moment(start).format('Do MMM, YYYY - h:mm a');
                    endFormatted = end ? moment(end).format('Do MMM, YYYY - h:mm a') : 'Sin fecha de fin';
                }

                // Rellenar los datos en el modal
                document.querySelector('[data-kt-calendar="event_name"]').textContent = title;
                document.querySelector('[data-kt-calendar="all_day"]').textContent = allDay ? 'Todo el día' : '';
                document.querySelector('[data-kt-calendar="event_start_date"]').textContent = startFormatted;
                document.querySelector('[data-kt-calendar="event_end_date"]').textContent = endFormatted;
                document.querySelector('[data-kt-calendar="event_description"]').textContent = description;
                document.querySelector('[data-kt-calendar="event_alert"]').textContent = alert;
                document.querySelector('[data-kt-calendar="event_task"]').textContent = task;

                // Mostrar el modal de Bootstrap
                const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('kt_modal_view_event'));
                modal.show();
            }
        });

        calendar.render();
  ensureGapiInitialized().then(loadCalendarEvents).catch(handleError);
    });

/*
    function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
    }

    async function initializeGapiClient() {
        try {
            await gapi.client.init({
                apiKey: "APIKEY",
                discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"],
            });
            gapiInited = true;
            // Load the calendar events after the client is initialized
            if (gisInited) {
                loadCalendarEvents();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error al inicializar gapi client:', error);
        }
    }

    function gisLoaded() {
        try {
            tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
                client_id: "CLIENTID",
                scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
                callback: '', // defined later
            });
            gisInited = true;
            // Load the calendar events after the client is initialized
            if (gapiInited) {
                loadCalendarEvents();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error: Configuración de Google no cargada correctamente.', error);
        }
    }
*/

    async function ensureGapiInitialized() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (typeof gapi !== 'undefined' && gapiInited && gisInited) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                const checkInterval = setInterval(() => {
                    if (typeof gapi !== 'undefined' && gapiInited && gisInited) {
                        clearInterval(checkInterval);
                        resolve();
                    }
                }, 100);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    clearInterval(checkInterval);
                    reject(new Error('Google Calendar API no está inicializada.'));
                }, 5000); // Timeout after 5 seconds
            }
        });
    }

    function loadCalendarEvents() {
        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
            if (resp.error !== undefined) {
                throw (resp);
            }
            const userInfo = await gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
            document.getElementById('accountName').innerText = userInfo.result.email;
            calendar.refetchEvents();
        };

        if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent', login_hint: 'user@example.com' });
        } else {
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: '' });
        }
    }

    function handleError(error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Error',
            text: 'Ocurrió un error. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde.',
        });
    }

    // CIERRE SESION
    async function cierre() {
        console.log('Cerrando sesión Google...');
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Cerrando sesión...',
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            didOpen: () => {
                Swal.showLoading();
            },
        });
        try {
            const token = gapi.client.getToken().access_token;
            if (token) {
                // Revocar el token de acceso
                await fetch(`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=${token}`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                });

                console.log('Token revocado correctamente');

                gapi.client.setToken(null);
                localStorage.removeItem('googleAccessToken');
                localStorage.setItem('logoutCompletedG', 'true');
                console.log('Sesión Google cerrada correctamente');
                Swal.close();
                
                const logoutWindow = window.open(`https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=${HomeUrl}`, '_blank', 'width=500,height=500');

                // Esperar unos segundos para asegurarse de que el cierre de sesión se complete
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if (logoutWindow) {
                        logoutWindow.close();
                    }
                    Swal.close();
                    window.location.href = HomeUrl;
                }, 3000);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            Swal.close();
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Error al cerrar sesión',
                text: 'Ocurrió un error al intentar cerrar sesión. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde.'
            });
            console.log('Error al cerrar sesión Google', error);
        }
    }
</script>

navbar.php aqui se inicia sesion y el navbar siempre esta presente en todas las paginas
<!-- Google API -->
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        //#region GOOGLE

        // URL calendario Google
        const calendarGoogleUrl = '<?php echo site_url('calendarGoogle'); ?>';

        let tokenClient;
        let gapiInited = false;
        let gisInited = false;

        // Inicializar el cliente de la API de Google
        async function initializeGapiClient() {
            try {
                await gapi.client.init({
                    apiKey: "API KEY",
                    discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"],
                });
                gapiInited = true;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error al inicializar gapi client:', error);
            }
        }

        function gapiLoaded() {
            gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
        }

        function gisLoaded() {
            try {
                tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
                    client_id: "CLIENT ID",
                    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
                    callback: '', // defined later
                    redirect_uri: '<?php echo site_url('calendarGoogle'); ?>',
                });
                gisInited = true;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error: Configuración de Google no cargada correctamente.', error);
            }
        }

        function mostrarCalendarioGoogle() {
            if (!gapiInited || !gisInited) {
                console.error("El cliente API de Google aún no se ha inicializado.");
                return;
            }
            try {
                handleAuthClick();
            } catch (error) {
                handleError(error);
            }
        }

        function handleAuthClick() {
            tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
                try {
                    if (resp.error !== undefined) {
                        throw (resp);
                    }
                    //Redirigir a la página del calendario de Google                
                    window.location.href = calendarGoogleUrl;
                } catch (error) {
                    handleError(error);
                }
            };

            if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
                tokenClient.requestAccessToken({
                    prompt: 'consent',
                    login_hint: 'user@example.com'
                });
            } else {
                tokenClient.requestAccessToken({
                    prompt: ''
                });
            }
        }

        //#endregion

        // BOTONES
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            document.getElementById('botonOutlook').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // Previene el comportamiento por defecto del enlace
                mostrarCalendarioOutlook();
            });

            document.getElementById('botonGoogle').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // Previene el comportamiento por defecto del enlace
                mostrarCalendarioGoogle();
            });
        });

        // ERRORES
        function handleError(error) {
            const errorCode = error.errorCode || error.error;

            if (error.errorCode === "interaction_in_progress") {
                console.warn('Interaction in progress, waiting for it to complete.');
            } else if (error.errorCode === "consent_required" || error.errorCode === "interaction_required") {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Permisos necesarios',
                    text: 'El administrador debe conceder los permisos necesarios para acceder a los calendarios. Contacta al administrador.'
                });
            } else if (error.errorCode === "access_denied") {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Acceso denegado',
                    text: 'No se pudo acceder a los datos solicitados. Verifica los permisos y vuelve a intentarlo.'
                });
            } else if (error.errorCode === "user_cancelled") {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Acción Cancelada',
                    text: 'Ha cancelado el inicio de sesión'
                });
            } else {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error de autenticación',
                    text: 'Ocurrió un error durante la autenticación. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde.'
                });
                console.error('Error durante la autenticación:', error);
            }
        }

        function goToCalendarEvent(event) {
            localStorage.setItem('event', JSON.stringify(event));
            window.location.replace('<?= site_url('calendar') ?>')
        }
    </script>

Si necesitan cualquier información no duden en pedirla
¡Muchísimas Gracias!

Maybe blocked by the browser?: ¿En qué navegadores hiciste las pruebas? ¿Tiene(n) bloqueadores de publicidad?

@padaleiana las pruebas las hago en Chrome y no uso ningun addBlock
